# How can I recreate the iOS App Store image slideshow?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

So I am pretty new to Swift still and I was wondering if anyone could help me recreate the image slideshow at the top of the iOS Appstore.

Is it a scrollview with UIImageViews or CollectionView cells?

I tried following and modifying [this Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76436/use-uiscrollview-scroll-zoom-content-swift) but the result I got *laisse à désirer* as can be seen in the image below.

Instead of three images showing I only got two and none completely filled the scrollView which leads me to think it might be a problem with auto layout.

Would really appreciate all the help I can get.

Anyway here is my code:

```
var pageImages = [UIImage]()
var pageViews: [UIImageView?] = []
@IBOutlet weak var carousel: UIScrollView!   

override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
    //Setting up the image carousel
    pageImages = [UIImage(named: "featured_1")!, UIImage(named: "featured_2")!, UIImage(named: "featured_3")!]
    for _ in 0..<pageImages.count {
        pageViews.append(nil)
    }
    let pagesScrollViewSize = carousel.frame.size
    carousel.contentSize = CGSize(width: pagesScrollViewSize.width * CGFloat(pageImages.count),
        height: pagesScrollViewSize.height)
}

func loadPage(page: Int) {
    if page < 0 || page >= pageImages.count {
        // If it's outside the range of what you have to display, then do nothing
        return
    }

    // 1
    if let pageView = pageViews[page] {
        // Do nothing. The view is already loaded.
    } else {
        // 2
        var frame = carousel.bounds
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(page)
        frame.origin.y = 0.0

        // 3
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: pageImages[page])
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        imageView.frame = frame
        carousel.addSubview(imageView)

        // 4
        pageViews[page] = imageView
    }
}

func purgePage(page: Int) {
    if page < 0 || page >= pageImages.count {
        // If it's outside the range of what you have to display, then do nothing
        return
    }

    // Remove a page from the scroll view and reset the container array
    if let pageView = pageViews[page] {
        pageView.removeFromSuperview()
        pageViews[page] = nil
    }
}

func loadVisiblePages() {
    // First, determine which page is currently visible
    let pageWidth = carousel.frame.size.width
    let page = Int(floor((carousel.contentOffset.x * 2.0 + pageWidth) / (pageWidth * 2.0)))

    // Work out which pages you want to load
    let firstPage = page - 1
    let lastPage = page + 1

    // Purge anything before the first page
    for var index = 0; index < firstPage; ++index {
        purgePage(index)
    }

    // Load pages in our range
    for index in firstPage...lastPage {
        loadPage(index)
    }

    // Purge anything after the last page
    for var index = lastPage+1; index < pageImages.count; ++index {
        purgePage(index)
    }
}

override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    loadVisiblePages()
    }
}
```

[image: The image views do not completely fill the scroll view and only two images appear even after scrolling]

Comment: You need to use a 'UIScrollView' with *Pagination* enabled.

Comment: @Woodstock Already doing both

Comment: "Is it a scrollview with UIImageViews or CollectionView cells?" Neither. The App Store app is a web view; the whole thing is done in CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: @matt If I wanted to recreate it in Swift, what would be the best approach and why didn't mine work?

Comment: @matt couldn't find anything that stood out

Comment: But that's what the debugger is for. Walk through your code and see what's really going on.

Comment: @matt thanks I guess, I'll try again :)

Comment: @Woodstock would you mind helping me out? Still can't figure it out